# Spring Prototype refering Singleton

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, concurrency, prototype-scope

I am using `ConcurrentTaskExecutor` to run the multiple tasks at the same time. By default in spring, it is scoped as *singleton*.

Here my `taskExecutor` is *prototype* and `threadPoolExecutor` is no.t

When requested a new `taskExecutor` is returned. My question is, since we are referring a `threadPoolExecutor` from prototype, will `threadPoolExecutor` be a new instance?

```
<bean id="taskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ConcurrentTaskExecutor" scope="prototype">
    <property name="concurrentExecutor" ref="threadPoolExecutor"/>
</bean>
<bean id="threadPoolExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor">
    <property name="corePoolSize" value="100" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="200" />
    <property name="queueCapacity" value="1000" />
</bean>
```

Comment: assuming that they are in the same context, then threadPoolExecutor will be singleton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "prototype" keyword just means that each time you ask Spring for an instance, you will get a fresh instance. With the wiring you have, you are only asking once. So I expect that your taskExecutor bean will be a single instance.

Answer (score 2):

No, the `prototype` keyword does not have "deep" scope. It does not apply to referenced or inner beans.

For the bean marked as prototype, i.e. `taskExecutor`, Spring will create a new instance every time you ask for it. But all those new taskExecutors will contain the same singleton instance of `threadPoolExecutor`.